# The efficient use of space

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means the study or practice of the efficient use of space, something ending -omics. I used to know it but I've got ergonomics stuck in my brain and that's not quite right.

Comment: [Agronomics](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/agronomics)? The branch of economics dealing with the distribution, management, and productivity of land. The word _economy_ itself could well be coaxed to fit within the boundaries of your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Although not pertaining solely to  efficient use of space, the word *[logistics](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logistics#Noun)* is relevant (emphasis added; commas as found):

> (operations) The process of planning, implementing, and controlling the efficient, effective flow and **storage** of goods, services and related information from their point of origin to point of consumption for the purpose of satisfying customer requirements.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy):

> The English words "economy" and "economics" can be traced back to the Greek words οἰκονόμος (i.e. "one who manages a household", a composite word derived from οἴκος ("house") and νέμω ("manage; distribute")) and οἰκονομία ("household management").
>   Leoni Schmidt
>   Playing With the image: 
>   in conversation with margaret Roberts

Since

> eco-nomics = management/planning of eco,

You would be looking for a technical jargon for spatial management/planning.

If you are allowed the liberty of coining a new term, it could be

> spationomics

Otherwise, you might have to rely on some existing mouthful terms

- spatio-economic efficiency
- spatio-efficiency
- spatiologic-efficiency
- spatiological planning

> [Henri Lefebvre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Lefebvre) coined the term “spatiology” to involve both physical space and social space. As a Marxist, Lefebvre was interested in the production of spatiology within a modern, urbanising capitalism. He attempted to trace generative moments in its production and for him “space becomes redescribed not as a dead, inert thing or object, but as organic and fluid and alive; it has a pulse, it palpates, it flows and collides with other spaces.” - 
>   [Leoni Schmidt -
>   Playing With the image: 
>   in conversation with margaret Roberts](http://junctures.org/index.php/junctures/article/viewFile/101/106)

Answer (score 0):

The Greek for *place* or *space* is χώρος, which suggests ***choronomics.***

However, this has specific uses in biology/zoology which may render it inapplicable in other situations. I had to resort to a Russian source; it's not listed in OED.

> [Choronomic](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/en_invertebrate_zoology/2725/choronomic)
>   *adj. [Gr. choros, place; nomos, place or condition for living]*
>       The external influences effecting [sic] animals, such as geographical or regional environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of [tessellation](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=tessellation&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=6dc4UaKpLcOqPMeHgegM&ved=0CDMQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k&fp=3fe8463959a88f3d&biw=1318&bih=897) *- the careful juxtaposition of shapes in a pattern.*
[image: xx]

My understanding is that tessellation is of great interest not just to artists such as M. C. Escher (who produced that one), but also to physicists and mathematicians such as [Roger Penrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling). And doubtless biologists, since DNA is very much concerned with protein-folding and shape-fitting.

So if OP wants a word relevant to an active area of scientific enquiry, *tessellation* is probably the one to go for. I don't think architects and [real-]estate agents have a technical word for how they manage to create/describe "spacious" living accommodation in tiny houses.

For a more "informal/quirky" term, most people would probably understand [Tardisification](http://www.guardian.co.uk/culture/2009/may/21/watch-this-television-preview) (by which means Doctor Who's [Tardis](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=tardis&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=cd04Uev-D8XcOf-LgMAE&ved=0CC8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k&fp=3fe8463959a88f3d&biw=1318&bih=897) is made much larger on the inside than the outside). But as of now I doubt you'd find that one in any dictionaries.

Comment: Also, I can't resist [tetristerone](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tetris%20packed) - the (usually female) hormone *which governs the ability to efficiently pack multiple objects of differing shapes, sizes, and colors (as they can be confusing) into a box or other container leaving minimal empty space.* It's the non-scientific version of Tardisification, that allows some women to have more in their handbag than the average man can fit in the boot of his car.

Answer (score 0):

Ergonomics is defined as human engineering, and often related to the efficient use of space. A pull-out bed or a folding desk could be described as economical designs.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps agoranomics? Agoraphobia is the fear of wide open spaces and according to etymologyonline it comes from the Greek *agora* "open space".

Comment: What? Did I get downvoted just because I made up a word? A completely sensible word. Man, I bet the same crap happened to the Bard too :(

Comment: Would the items in my suitcase get traumatised by agoraphobia when I practice "agornomics" on them to pack as much stuffs as possible in as small a luggage bag that the airline would then permit me to store in overhead bins rather than having me check the bag in as baggage? LOL - didn't vote you down but your answer is hilarious.

Comment: @Blessed Geek: No, that would be claustrophobia; the fear of cramped spaces.

Comment: You are right - got a little mixed up.